# How to fork another Python process from a PYInstaller created EXE

Tags: python, fork, exe, pyinstaller

I'm trying to fork another Python process from a running Python (ProgramA.pyc) module that is started from within the pyinstaller exe runtime environment.

Point is that ProgramA runs fine. I cannot however ProgramB to get started from that same runtime environment. I need to emphasize that I need to start and run it (from the ProgramA module) like:

```
python ProgramB.pyc.
```

I do not want to import ProgramB into ProgramA since when it executes, it then blocks the GUI of ProgramA. ProgramB module is a blocking one due to the smtplib module it calls.

Simply starting the ProgramB.pyc from the MEIPASS temp dir is neither a solution since it then does not have the Python scripts and other runtime requirements available (that otherwise comes from the .exe produced by pyinstaller).

In the development environment I can start ProgramB from ProgramA and it is then indeed non-blocking since it uses another Python interpreter (all without pyinstaller).

How to do such from an executable produced by pyinstaller?

Note:
The ProgramB module is inside the exe produced by pyinstaller and is available in the MEIPASS dir. But that one does not get any environment settings from the extracted .exe.